# Boundary conditions for self-adjoint linear diffrential operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, greens-function

I am from chemistry background, trying to grasp application of Green's function. In the book "Application of Green's function in Science and Engineering" by MD Greenberg, on page 58-59, Following is written:

> Whereas $u =0$ on C (boundary condition), the normal derivative $u_n$ is not specified, and hence need not be zero. For the boundary terms to vanish we therefore need $v=0$.

Why? I mean why can't we assume that $u_n$ might not be zero, but we have no problem in assuming $v=0$?

Also being tangentially on same topic, on page 57 following is given which is  not clear, 
$(v\nabla u - u\nabla v).\textbf{n} = v\partial u/\partial n - u\partial v/ \partial n$

I can't understand how?

Comment: Note that $\nabla u \cdot n$ is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ and that the dot product is linear.